# how to search data from a table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, search

can any one post any link/tutorial which will explain how  to search data from a table in sql server ,like using some stored procedure...any example?
In details:
Lets say I have a table havinh columns ID,title,username description etc, so now first it will search for username and then title and so on.

Comment: Very Unclear question. Can you tell at least if you're searching on a whole field, or just some text in big text blog on every line ?

Comment: is your question about 'searching' or about the basics of retrieving data from a database or really about the more advanced topic of 'stored procedures' which I assume it is not looking at the example you make. read some other question and some stuff on the web about database and then come back and ask your question in a more concrete way.

Comment: Maybe that's something for you: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/database/article.php/3478051 If you know all of that and your question really is about something more sophisticated, make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @search nvarchar(50)
set @Search = 'Some String'


SELECT 
        * 
FROM 
        Table
WHERE 
        Username like '%' + @search + '%' 
OR 
        Description like '%' + @search + '%' 
OR  
        Title like '%' + @search + '%'
```

Is that what you're getting at ?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP and MS SQL you have to do something like this.

```
<?PHP  if(isset($_POST['buttonsearch']))
      {
      $key_search = (isset($_POST['txtsearch_client']) ? $_POST['txttxtsearch_client'] : '#');


      $query_se = "SELECT TOP(10) *
                   FROM clients WHERE clientid  LIKE '%{$key_search}%' OR
                                       clientfname LIKE '%{$key_search}%' OR
                                       clientlname LIKE '%{$key_search}%'
                                                   ORDER BY clientid DESC";

      }
      $sql_se = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query_se);
      if( $sql_se === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
                            }


      while( $obj_se = sqlsrv_fetch_object($sql_se)) {
            echo "<tr>
                       <td> $obj_se->clientid </td>
                       <td> $obj_se->clientfname </td>
                       <td> $obj_se->clientlname </td>
                  <tr>";                             } 
       exit();


   ?>
```